# Is it Possible to use html input tag in forms for image capture on smartphones but save to the photo to the device gallery at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html, camera, smartphone

Is there a way with Javascript or HTML for images to be saved to the device gallery when you use the input tag with image capture?

I used an input tag for image capture like this:

```
<input type="file"
       name="picture"
       accept="image/*"
       capture="user">
```

It allows input of the photo into a form but doesn't save it to the gallery at the same time.